# How to email with emacs with MS Exchange Server

Tags: email, emacs, exchange

I'm using emacs 23.1.x on centos 6.0. I'd like to be able to read/send emails on the corporate MS Exchange server. What is the procedure for doing the same ?

thank you.

Comment: From the [Gnus FAQ](http://www.gnus.org/manual/gnus_397.html#SEC446): Q: "At the office we use one of those MS Exchange servers, can I use Gnus to read my mail from it?"  A: "Offer your administrator a pair of new running shoes for activating IMAP on the server and follow the instructions above."  Hopefully there are alternative solutions...

Comment: do you want to make your comment as an answer. I will accept it as one. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Gnus FAQ](http://www.gnus.org/manual/gnus_397.html#SEC446):

> **Question 3.10**
>
> At the office we use one of those MS Exchange servers, can I use Gnus to read my mail from it?
>
> **Answer**
>
> Offer your administrator a pair of new running shoes for activating IMAP on the server and follow the instructions above.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/), which should be able to do this: it acts as a proxy server, accessing the Exchange server with the proprietary protocol and allowing access to clients through IMAP and SMTP (among other protocols).